# Error with using zeppelin z.put function when using spark and kafka

Tags: angularjs, apache-spark, apache-kafka, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am trying to use spark, kafka in zeppelin notebook with the code below. 
    %pyspark

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

ssc = StreamingContext(sc,60)
broker = "127.0.0.1:9092"
directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ["testlogs"],{"metadata.broker.list": broker})
lines = directKafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1])


f1 = lines.filter(lambda x: x[2])
f2 = f1.map(lambda x: (x.split(",")[4]))
f3 = f2.map(lambda x: (x.split(":")[1]))
f4 = f3.map(lambda x: x)
f5 = f4.filter(lambda x: x == "test string")
f6 = f5.count()
f6.pprint() 
#Above prints correct count on the console


z.put('m0_count', str(f6))

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(300)


%spark

z.angularBind("m0_count", z.get("m0_count"))


%angular

<html>
<h2>Table</h2>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"><center><h3>my count</h3>{{m0_count}}</center></div>
    </div>
    <br />
</html>
```

I get the following error in my angularjs table:
      "pyspark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream object at 0x7fdc797c3b90"

Could anyone please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: try, `f7 = str(f6)` and then `print f7` to see what prints out

Comment: I get the same error printed on console now. Not sure how to pass the value of f6 to z.put in zeppelin.Please advise. <pyspark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream object at 0x7f1016a0d650>